# Slow access to files on network drive from Hyper-V guest

Tags: windows, networking, hyper-v

Windows Server 2022 with Hyper-V on Dell PowerEdge R550.

On Hyper-v there is a Windows Server 2016 guest which is an  Active Directory Domain Controller.

Accessing a file from Windows Server 2016 is  slow, one small file open requires 5 minutes+.

I don't know why and what's going on.

From Windows Server 2022 the access is normal.